# Start timer after new item is added to List<T>

Tags: c#

I am designing a windows service which interacts with Harris automation sytem (triggers), inside I have an EPG collection, each EPG item has a type : A = Adv / S = Series / ....

My need :

If new trigger comes with  type A (Adv), then start computing seconds, and once this timespan is >= 2 minutes , delete associated EPG from the collection.

Is this can be performed by using some kind of Event / Delegate / timer.. ?

Since it's related to a powerful third part "Harris" i need also a powerful solution to perform this (trigger periodicity 150 trigger / seconds).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a `List<>`, you can try using a `BindingList<>`, which does have events:

Example:

```
BindingList<yourClass> eventList = new BindingList<yourClass>();

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  eventList.ListChanged += new ListChangedEventHandler(eventList_ListChanged);
}

void eventList_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e) {
  if (e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemAdded) {
    // something was added
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new `TriggeredList<T>` which inherits from `List<T>` and overwrite the `Add(T item)`-method to create a timer in case you just added an A-Trigger.

The add method should look something like this:

```
public override void Add (T item)
{
    // code do start timer/whatever
    base.Add(item);
}
```

Also you should overwrite the Remove method or something else to delete/stop your timer.

Comment: As a follow-on to this - if `Add` is all you're overriding, it's probably a good idea to use the decorator pattern and forward all calls to the contained list, rather than re-implementing them.

Comment: Of course, I assumed it and forgot to mention that :) Thanks for the tip